# Php page to execute a script

Tags: php, execute

can i create a page with a simple text area form, which will be entered PHP CODE and then, when i click to submit, it executes it? just like a Script page?

and most of all it is secure to put it? even in a admin protected page?

thankyou!

Comment: Yes, you can!!! Actually, there is no reason to ask exact the same twice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a code in php inside an if that allows only admin to execute is protected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653956/does-a-code-in-php-inside-an-if-that-allows-only-admin-to-execute-is-protected)

Comment: its a different question! that question is for overall admin pages, this one is if is  possible and secure to do a execute-script page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can:

```
eval($_POST['txtScript']); //post method, with textarea named txtScript
```

However, it is **extremely** dangerous to permit this. Someone could wipe the current working directory via `array_map("unlink", glob('*.*'));` among the many, many other malicious things that could be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowing someone to author PHP code on a form and then, on submission, taking that PHP code and executing it, you're opening yourself up to HUGE, **HUGE** security risks. Is it possible to do? Sure, but I would highly recommend against doing it.

If you're absolutely sure you need to do this, read about the `eval` function. [PHP: eval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Answer (score 0):

you want to use [PHP:eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), and no it is not safe even behind a login wall. Better put some predefined function that can be logged.

And of course, by definition anything you put as accessible is quite unsafe anyway.